# GitLab Terraform module registry with HTTP discovery

Tags: gitlab, terraform

I've been setting up the Terraform registry from GitLab. My setup seems correct but I face the issue below:

```
    Initializing modules...
21╷
22│ Error: Error accessing remote module registry
23│
24│ Failed to retrieve available versions for module "azure_vm" (main.tf:1)
25│ from eucceisgtp01.pvcp.intra: Failed to request discovery document: Get "https://eucceisgtp01.pvcp.intra/.well-known/terraform.json": dial tcp
27│ 172.18.3.44:443: connect: connection refused.
```

due to GitLab accepting only HTTPS requests for the discovery. Do you know how and where it can be switched to HTTP?